# Extract a number in table with bash

Tags: bash, extract

I have a log txt file below:

```
Data                                         

 Adress                Member     Year old         Birthday 

1600 queen street      Male        6               04/15/17
```

I want to extract only the number of "Year old" and use it in variable after on my script like:

```
if [ $oldregistered != $newold ]
then
        echo "The year old has changed !"
else
        echo "Nothing to do, stay young !"
fi
```

How do I extract the number of "Year old" from my log file?

Comment: Is your log file tab-separated?

Comment: is there only one string of data in the table?

Comment: Why do this in Bash when databases are designed to this for you?

Comment: Yes my log fiel tab is separated.I want to check if the year old has been changed or no.

Comment: And there are empty lines in your input file, and the second non-empty line starts with a space?

Comment: Yes, it's a outpout result from the log, my colaborator do that but now he is not here anymore to help me to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

You need a 'field delimiter' - (looks like 'tabs' are in use). There are many approaches for this - awk example follows:

```
echo "1600 queen street  | Male | 6 | 04/15/17" | awk -F '|' '{print $3}'
```

Above, we set the delimiter to a pipe symbol, then have awk show us the third 'field'.

If tabs are being used, then something like:

```
newold=$(awk -F '\t' '{print $3}' /path/some_file.log.txt)
```

The above should work for you as long as your file **only contains one line of data**, otherwise awk will iterate over each line and print the 3rd field.  If your source file contains multiple data lines then you will need to 'pre-select' the line of interest (i.e. via egrep) and send only the one line to the awk command.

:)
Dale